# Is it possible to make parseFloat from several textboxes?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to read and handle numerical values from 2 textboxes, using parseFloat? Such code does not work for me. I suspect the problem is somehow connected with the second textbox?!

```html
<div style="padding:10px;">
    Enter number 1: <input class="textbox" value=""/>
</div>
<div style="padding:10px;">
    Enter number 2: <input class="textbox2" value=""/>
</div>
<div>
    <button id="Get">Calculate</button> 
</div>
<div>
    <h4>Result: <label id="msg"></label></h4>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("button:#Get").click(function () {
    var num1 = parseFloat($('input:textbox').val());
    var num2 = parseFloat($('input:textbox2').val());
    var result = ((num1 * num2));
    $('#msg').html(result);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the selectors.

```
$(document).on('click','button#Get',function () {        
    var num1 = parseFloat($('input.textbox').val());
    var num2 = parseFloat($('input.textbox2').val());
    var result = ((num1*num2)); 
    $('#msg').html(result);  
});
```

This will work independent of position of the script tag.

Answer (score 2):

You may be reading the textboxes incorrectly. Try:

```
$("button#Get").click(function () {
    var num1 = parseFloat($('input.textbox').val());
    var num2 = parseFloat($('input.textbox2').val());
    var result = ((num1*num2)); 
    $('#msg').html(result);         
});
```

and see if you now get the correct results. The selector you needed for the button was `button#Get` rather than `button:#Get`, whilst the textboxes were `input.textbox` and `input.textbox2`, not `input:textbox` and `input:textbox2`. The `:` syntax is generally for checking certain attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
$("#Get").click(function () {
    var num1 = parseFloat($('input.textbox').val()),
    num2 = parseFloat($('input.textbox2').val()),
    result = ((num1*num2)); 
    $('#msg').html(result);         
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Rusqj/).

The problem appears to be your confusion as regards jQuery selectors; a `:` prefaces a selector (such as `:eq()`, `:first` etc), whereas a period (`.`) should preface a class-name.

Similarly an `id` should be unique within the document, so the tag-name (unless your script runs on multiple pages, where the `id` might be attached to a different type of element) isn't required, and there's certainly no need for the `:` characters there.